# Showing that the difference of two random varialbes is symmetric

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two iid random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$. I want to show that $X - Y$ has a symmetric distribution. I know that $\mathbb P_X(A) = \mathbb P_Y(A)$ for every $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. How can I show that $\mathbb P_{X-Y} (A) = \mathbb P_{Y-X}(A)$ for every $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$? I know that it should be enough to analyze the family of intervals $(\infty, x]$, but I don't see how I can relate $\mathbb P(Y\leq x) = \mathbb P(X \leq x)$ to $\mathbb P(X - Y \leq x) = P(Y - X \leq x)$.

Comment: You probably meant $X,Y$ are independent, identically distributed, right? Note that those assumptions imply $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ have the same distributions. This means that for any borel $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ random variables $f(X,Y)$ and $f(Y,X)$ have the same distribution. Do you see which $f$ to choose?

Comment: @DominikKutek: $f(u, v) = u - v$

Comment: Exactly, then $X-Y = f(X,Y) \sim f(Y,X) = Y-X$, where $\sim$ means equality in distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P_X$ and $P_Y$ denote the distribution of $X$ and $Y$. Then,
$$
P_{X-Y}(A)= \mathbb{E}{[\mathbb{1}\{X-Y\in A\}]}=\\\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathbb1\{x-y \in A\} dP_X(x)dP_Y(y)
$$
Since $P_X$ and $P_Y$ are equal, we can write
$$P_{X-Y}(A)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathbb1\{x-y \in A\} dP_Y(x)dP_X(y)$$.
Then, by the change of variable $x \leftarrow y$ and $y \leftarrow x$, we have
$$P_{X-Y}(A)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathbb1\{y-x \in A\} dP_Y(y)dP_X(x)\\
=P_{Y-X}(A)$$.